# Is there a Scrum plugin for the Roundup Issue Tracker?

Tags: python, agile, scrum, trac, roundup

Is there a Scrum plugin for the [Roundup Issue Tracker](http://roundup.sourceforge.net/) similar to [Agilo](http://www.agile42.com/cms/pages/agilo/) for [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)? I realize that [Roundup](http://roundup.sourceforge.net/) is an issue tracking system, whereas [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is designed to be an integrated project management, SCM, and issue tracker. Therefore, maybe a better question would be—Is anyone aware of a, preferably Python based, Scrum tool to use in conjunction with [Roundup](http://roundup.sourceforge.net/)? Although, that may be a bit too subjective for this forum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (You can also flag for moderator intervention to have this question migrated.)

Comment: @robinCTS flagging won't get it migrated, [even moderators can't migrate a question after 60 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258349/can-or-cant-questions-be-migrated-after-60-days).

Comment: @River Thanks. I'd already found that out, but only *after* I'd sent out the first batch of close votes. (Don't know where I got the impression that mods could still migrate old questions. Something twigged as I was sending out the last few, so decided to double check.) I've updated my boilerplate message. Was wondering if I'd get a correction from somebody. You're the only one so far, from 30-40 close votes. PS Just got another correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this some more, it appears that there is not a Scrum plugin for the [Roundup Issue Tracker](http://roundup.sourceforge.net/) similar to [Agilo](http://www.agile42.com/cms/pages/agilo/) for [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). However, I was able to find [Ajellito](http://www.ajellito.com/) (formerly Agilito). From the [Ajellito](http://www.ajellito.com/) website:

> Simple, web-based Agile / Scrum project management tool built in Django
>   Ajellito aims to do just enough for you to effectively and efficiently manage projects using an Agile methodology.

Given that [Ajellito](http://www.ajellito.com/) is written in [Django](http://djangoproject.com/)—a Python web framework—this may be a nice complement to [Roundup](http://roundup.sourceforge.net/).

Using [Ajellito](http://www.ajellito.com/) for tracking user stories and tasks/actions and [Roundup](http://roundup.sourceforge.net/) to track bugs/defects presents a new problem in terms of integration, or lack thereof, between the actions/tasks and bugs/defects.

[Agile Database Integration http://img.skitch.com/20100104-t3crikk3hjb1mrmmnuipsk5fj7.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100104-t3crikk3hjb1mrmmnuipsk5fj7.jpg)